# Data not getting passed to redux

Tags: redux, redux-toolkit

This is my data

```
    import React, { useEffect, useState,CSSProperties } from "react";
      import img from "../../../public/images/home/desktop/headphone-hero-image.png"
      import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
      import AliceCarousel from 'react-alice-carousel';
      import 'react-alice-carousel/lib/alice-carousel.css';
      import axios from "axios"
      import 'react-dropdown/style.css';
      import {useSelector,useDispatch} from "react-redux"
      import Dropdown from 'react-dropdown';
      import { addtocart } from "../redux/cartslice";
      export default function Product()
    
      {
    //redux
    
    const dispatch=useDispatch();
      
    
      /// for the selector dropdoen
      const[values,setvalue]=useState(2)
      
    
      const handleDragStart = (e) => e.preventDefault();
      
      
    
      const onselect=()=>{
        console.log(values)
      }
      //carousel
      const items = [
      <img src={img} onDragStart={handleDragStart} role="presentation" />,
      <img src={img} onDragStart={handleDragStart} role="presentation" />,
      <img src={img} onDragStart={handleDragStart} role="presentation" />,
      ];
    
    
      ///////for id
    
      const { id } = useParams();
      console.log(id)
    //getting data
    const [data, setData] = useState({});
    
    useEffect(() => {
     
    }, [data]);
    
    useEffect(() => {
      const getData = async () => {
        const response = await axios.get(`/api/product/find/${id}`);
        setData(response.data.exist);
      };
      getData();
    }, [id]);
    
    const add = async () => {
      try {
        if(data){
         
        dispatch(
          addtocart({
            
            data,
            values,
          })
        );
        }
    
        const response = await axios.post("/api/cart/add", {
          itemId: id,
          quantity: values,
        });
        console.log(response);
        console.log(data);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err.response.data);
      }
    };
```

my redux is

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';


export const cartSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'cart',
  initialState: {
    items: []
  },
  reducers: {
    addtocart: (state, action) => {
      const newItem = action.payload?.data;
      const { values } = action.payload;
      const existingItem = state.items.find((item) => item.id === newItem.id);
      if (!existingItem) {
        state.items.push({
          id: newItem._id,
          name: newItem.name,
          price: newItem.price,
          quantity: values,
        });
       
      } 

        
      
    },
    remove:(state,action)=>
    {
      const id=action.payload._id
      const existingcart=items.find((item)=>item._id===_id);
      if(existingcart)
      {
        state.items=state.items.filter(item=>item._id!==_id);
       
      }
  
      
    },
    reset:(state)=>{
      state.items=[]
    }
   
  },
});

export const { addtocart,remove,reset} = cartSlice.actions;

export default cartSlice.reducer;
```

whenever I try to push data I am getting a data undefined error. Tried many solutions but not working.Any help will be appreciated
Error is:
Product.jsx:78 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data')
Console logging data just before the dispatch correctly fetches the data but not getting updated
I have defined store in other file

Comment: Have you called createStore function?

Comment: Ref: https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createSlice#examples

Comment: @RK_oo7 yes create store is added